# Why when retrieve data from fire base it retrieve null?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when i try to retrieve  data from firebase it retrieve  a null object and the data is already exist in the child  this the state of the firebase

[The firebase tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzRi5.jpg)

```
sensorValue
{
  "ldrSensorValue" : 1021,
  "potSensorValue" : 820,
  "temperatureSensorValue" : 29.33
}
```

This is the class:

```
public class SensorsValues {

private double temperatureSensorValue;
private double ldrSensorValue;
private double potSensorValue;


public SensorsValues() {
}

public SensorsValues(double temperatureSensorValue, double ldrSensorValue, double potSensorValue) {
    this.temperatureSensorValue = temperatureSensorValue;
    this.ldrSensorValue = ldrSensorValue;
    this.potSensorValue = potSensorValue;
}

public double getTemperatureSensorValue() {
    return temperatureSensorValue;
}

public double getLdrSensorValue() {
    return ldrSensorValue;
}

public double getPotSensorValue() {
    return potSensorValue;
}

public void setTemperatureSensorValue(double temperatureSensorValue) {
    this.temperatureSensorValue = temperatureSensorValue;
}

public void setLdrSensorValue(double ldrSensorValue) {
    this.ldrSensorValue = ldrSensorValue;
}

public void setPotSensorValue(double potSensorValue) {
    this.potSensorValue = potSensorValue;
}
}
```

This the place of the code where I retrieve the data

```
    //set up the firebase
  mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("sensorValue");
  mSendDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("sendCommands");

  mSensorsValueschildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        //when new message is inserted this method is called
        //for every child is exist this will called
        //DataSnapshot contain data from the database at certain position
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        //this called when the content of exiting data is changed
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //pass class when the child has the same child in the class
           SensorsValues sensorsValues =  dataSnapshot.child("sensorValue").getValue(SensorsValues.class);


            //get the sensors value
           /* tempSensorValue = sensorsValues.getTemperatureSensorValue();
            ldrSensorValue = sensorsValues.getLdrSensorValue();
            potSensorValue = sensorsValues.getPotSensorValue();*/
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,sensorsValues+"");

        }
        //this called when the content of exiting data is removed

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
        //this called when the content of exiting data is moved mean change it's position

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        //call when error happen when try to change some data
        //most when you don't have permission to read the data
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mSensorsValueschildEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is saying that one (or more) elements that Firebase thinks are of type Long (based on how you stored them into Firebase Database) can't be casted to double (the type of the variables inside SensorValues class).

So, to solve the error, try to store (for example) 734.0 instead of 734 (and so on). In this way Firebase can cast correctly the numbers to double.

Hope you can solve.

Comment: ok thank you for this answer i updated my class to have two int variable and one double  and i stored them in the firebase  in this way and after i try to retrieve it case the same error   `                                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.ahmed.bluetoothmodule.SensorsValues
`

Comment: `SensorsValues sensorsValuesSend = new SensorsValues(tempSensorValue, ldrSensorValue, potSensorValue);
                mDatabaseReference.setValue(sensorsValuesSend);`

Comment: `sensorsValues.setTemperatureSensorValue(Double.parseDouble(sensorsValueList.get(0)));
                    tempSensorValue = sensorsValues.getTemperatureSensorValue();

                    sensorsValues.setLdrSensorValue(Integer.parseInt(sensorsValueList.get(1)));
                    ldrSensorValue = sensorsValues.getLdrSensorValue();

                    sensorsValues.setPotSensorValue(Integer.parseInt(sensorsValueList.get(2)));
                    potSensorValue = sensorsValues.getPotSensorValue();`

Comment: Seems you're retrieving from an incorrect path the values. Instead of this: SensorsValues sensorsValues =  dataSnapshot.child("sensorValue").getValue(SensorsValues.class); inside the onChildChanged, try to do this: dataSnapshot.getValue(SensorsValues.class);

Comment: Try to change the event listener you are using. You are going to read and write a single object (if I've understood well your firebase tree), so try to use a ValueEventListener instead of ChildEventListener. More here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to call .child("sensorValue") on the datasnapshot
do it like this

```
 SensorsValues sensorsValues =  dataSnapshot.getValue(SensorsValues.class);
```

Comment: it still retrieve a null

Comment: Please add your complete firebase tree

Comment: `
{
  "sendCommands": {
    "-KbbPdg7OZSrG04-06CQ": "o",
    "-KbbPdz6w70h1LkO-vy4": "o",
    "-KbbPeEzE6noC9ngMnaD": "f",
    "-KbbPeN0usRFvT5Lm8zr": "o",
    "-KbbPjEQD620mg1CC4MA": "dis"

  },
  "sensorValue": {
    "ldrSensorValue": 1023,
    "potSensorValue": 734,
    "temperatureSensorValue": 26.88
  },
  "sensorsValues": {
    "-KbbK5PsTDNxqGi849A8": {
      "ldrSensorValue": 1023,
      "potSensorValue": 721,
      "temperatureSensorValue": 22.969999313354492
    }
  }
}`

Comment: i added a screen shot of the tree in the question

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.ahmed.bluetoothmodule, PID: 30567
                                                                                   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.ahmed.bluetoothmodule.SensorsValues`